# Counting elements which satisfy if statement and use this counter in list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, count, list-comprehension

For example, we have task, select first ten even numbers in the list.

This can be easily done with simple **for** loop:

```
i = 0
list_even = []
for x in range(30):
    if x % 2 == 0 and i < 10:
        list_even.append(x)
        i += 1
print(list_even)    # [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18] - correct!
```

How is it possible to do same with list-comprehension?

I have tried to use enumerate, but it counts all elements, not only that satisfy if statement, so I can't use the index from enumerate as counter.

```
list_even = [x for i, x in enumerate(range(30)) if x % 2 == 0 and i < 10]
print(list_even)    # [0, 2, 4, 6, 8] - incorrect!
```

The task I describe is just example - I am writing article about list comprehensions and want to understand details and general solution for such class of tasks.

Comment: shouldn't be `i < 20`? be cause you add `i `when it's even but you iterate over `i` in list comprehension every loop.

Comment: Aman, and if there is no range(), but some random numbers in collection? What i use in that case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First just filter, then count only the already filtered values?

```
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(x for x in range(30) if x % 2 == 0) if i < 10]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Though `islice` might be a better way to say you only want the first 10:

```
>>> list(itertools.islice((x for x in range(30) if x % 2 == 0), 10))
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Or just taking a slice of the full list, if time/space aren't an issue:

```
>>> [x for x in range(30) if x % 2 == 0][:10]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Comment: After all, `islice()` approach is the best way to go!

Comment: 1-st and 3-d variants are slow on huge collections, but 2-d variant (with itertools.islice() ) is perfect! It works only till we select necessary 10 elements!